# how to get the response of a request in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to call this url http://www.localhost:8585/doctorsite/login.php?username=xxx&password=password (a php restful web service) using javascript or jquery or ajax. And an xml values is returned as response. I want to store that response in an variable. Please help me regarding this.

I am trying this for creating iphone applications using phonegap.

Comment: *What have you tried*?

Comment: You know what's www.google.de for? Laziness reached a new level...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

huh.... have you try to take a look at jQuery documentation ?

you can use that ... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/